# IPv6 & ReservedPorts in Windows Server 2008 registry

Tags: windows-server-2008, ipv6, tcpip

I have `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\ReservedPorts` set to `1153-1153`, but sometimes IPv6 programs get assigned this port.  Is this setting for IPv4 only?  Is their another place to set this for IPv6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Server 2008 and 2008 R2 no longer support the ReservedPorts registry entry.

Instead, use the netsh utility to reserve ports, like so:

```
netsh int <ipv4|ipv6> Add excludedportrange [protocol=]tcp|udp [startport=]<integer> [numberofports=]<integer> [[store=]active|persistent]
```

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2665809/en-us

Edit: You also might need to install the Windows hotfix first found at the above MS Support KB.

Comment: This `netsh` command also works in Server 2012/R2.  The hotfix mentioned in the referenced KB article is not needed.